# Quickbook get Accesstoken Issue while using the phpsdk

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Trying to connect with quickbook using sandbox, but after authorization it showing the issue of the signature.

Any one who have done this before can send me the working sample code in php.

```
OAuthException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 401
    [file:protected] => /var/www/mssdev/quickbook/PHPSample/Test/oauth.php
    [line:protected] => 37
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/mssdev/quickbook/PHPSample/Test/oauth.php
                    [line] => 37
                    [function] => getAccessToken
                    [class] => OAuth
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [lastResponse] => oauth_problem=signature_invalid
    [debugInfo] => Array
        (
            [sbs] => GET&https%3A%2F%2Foauth.intuit.com%2Foauth%2Fv1%2Fget_access_token&oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdVAVnQU3sqJFd8R2SfksB73AXF%26oauth_nonce%3D1585561009557178083e35b6.09089809%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1433499656%26oauth_token%3DqyprdwSq502Ge9SEEBRIJ2ybhPCFtX7lo7H0gtGOPoGFGKrF%26oauth_verifier%3Ddrg9rff%26oauth_version%3D1.0
            [headers_recv] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 05 Jun 2015 10:20:58 GMT
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid"
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 31
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
            [body_recv] => oauth_problem=signature_invalid
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with this code from GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Follow this quick-start guide:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

You'll end up running these examples:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3